# Checking PC Date region in Excel/VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any VBA function that lets me check a PC date format (regional setting). This is set within the Control Panel -> Region and Language.

Michael

Comment: May I ask what you really like to achieve? Usually you shouldn't need that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this a couple of years back which I use to check the regional date format:

```
Function DateFormat() As String
  DateFormat = CStr(DateSerial(1999, 1, 2))
  DateFormat = Replace(DateFormat, "1999", "YYYY")
  DateFormat = Replace(DateFormat, "99", "YY")
  DateFormat = Replace(DateFormat, "01", "MM")
  DateFormat = Replace(DateFormat, "1", "M")
  DateFormat = Replace(DateFormat, "02", "dd")
  DateFormat = Replace(DateFormat, "2", "d")
  DateFormat = Replace(DateFormat, MonthName(1), "MMMM")
  DateFormat = Replace(DateFormat, MonthName(1, True), "MMM")
End Function
```

So on my set-up here, the function returns: dd/MM/YYYY

Answer (score 0):

You can [read this data from the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345238/read-and-write-from-to-registry-in-vba) at

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Internationaly\
```

- `sLongDate` represents the long date e.g. `dddd, d. MMMM yyyy`
- `sShortDate` represents the short date e.g. `yyyy-MM-dd`