# Get installed program (WhatsApp) path using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, whatsapp

I am trying to detect the path for the installed whatsapp and I have found this code that is working for excel.exe but not for WhatsApp.exe

```
#If Win64 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function FindExecutable Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "FindExecutableA" _
        (ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal lpResult As String) As Long
#Else
    Declare Function FindExecutable Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "FindExecutableA" _
        (ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal lpResult As String) As Long
#End If

Const SYS_OUT_OF_MEM        As Long = &H0
Const ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND  As Long = &H2
Const ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND  As Long = &H3
Const ERROR_BAD_FORMAT      As Long = &HB
Const NO_ASSOC_FILE         As Long = &H1F
Const MIN_SUCCESS_LNG       As Long = &H20
Const MAX_PATH              As Long = &H104

Const USR_NULL              As String = "NULL"
Const S_DIR                 As String = "C:\"


Function GetInstallDirectory(ByVal usProgName As String) As String

    Dim fRetPath As String * MAX_PATH
    Dim fRetLng As Long

    fRetLng = FindExecutable(usProgName, S_DIR, fRetPath)

    If fRetLng >= MIN_SUCCESS_LNG Then
        GetInstallDirectory = Left$(Trim$(fRetPath), InStrRev(Trim$(fRetPath), "\"))
    End If

End Function

Sub ExampleUse()

Dim x As String

x = "excel.exe"

Debug.Print GetInstallDirectory(x)

End Sub
```

How can I make this code work for checking the path of the WhatsApp.exe?

I tried such a code that works with excel.exe too but not fot the WhatsApp

```
Sub vv()
Dim WSHShell
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'MS Excel
MsgBox WSHShell.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\WhatsApp.exe\")
End Sub
```

Comment: isn't WhatsApp a website?

Comment: Yes and there's a software that can be installed ..

Comment: and you cant just search the registry?

Comment: Is it possible to use the registry for that purpose through VBA code? Can you show me, please?

Comment: this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345238/read-and-write-from-to-registry-in-vba

Comment: Thanks a lot but I can't find a clue. I have updated the post.

Comment: Why would you look in `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows`? Is WhatsApp a program written by Microsoft?

Comment: You are right. But I tried to find the path of it but the PC hanged when searching the registry..Can you give me te\he right path for it?

Comment: i dont have it installed, sorry... maybe you can look it up using google? First, figure out the name of the company who wrote it - that's a good place to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
 Sub test()
 Dim WSHShell
 Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 MsgBox WSHShell.RegRead("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp\shell\open\command\")
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the awesome help.