# Programmatically Add Min/Max to Status Bar in Bottom Right Corner in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, batch-file, registry

I'd like to manipulate the status bar in Excel via VBA. I want to add Min/Max and perhaps more manipulations, but for now, that is the goal. I tried using the Macro Recorder, but it didn't pick anything up. To do it manually you just right click in the status bar and then select "Max/Min" and it shows. Is there a hidden way to adjust this via VBA?

Note: *I'm* using Office 2013 x32, but I have many end users who might be using *newer* versions such as Office 365 and/or x64 version of Excel, but nothing *older*

[image]

Comment: I think your best bet is just displaying these values via `Application.StatusBar`

Comment: Make you vba check for updates and update itself as necessary - that’s how we did it with users across 4 countries. Something simple like the vba running checks its own serial number against a server held value - if the server value is different the call update routine.

Comment: I am curious as to why you want a status/progress bar unless it is in a userform. What I have observed is, while macro is running, due to constant screen updating none of the messages in status bar is readable.

Comment: @dwirony My goal is to have this function in the status bar available for users to learn to use with all spreadsheets, not just display the results of a macro. I have seen a slight workaround using `worksheet_change` event to basically replicate the status bar vs calculating totals after a macro to display, but that's a lot of coding logic that Excel already has built in, just need to enable it programmatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values are set in the Windows Registry

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\StatusBar\
```

Make sure `16.0` is replaced by the internal Office version number, that your users are using.

The registry keys are

- `MaxValue`
- `MinValue`

and they are of type `REG_DWORD` and `1` is enabled where `0` is disabled.

Note that after setting the registry keys you need to restart Excel no matter which of the following solutions you choose.

#### Solution 1: Group Policy

Set them via GPO (Group Policy) on your server and everyone has it enabled automatically with the next launch of Excel.

#### Solution 2: VBA

Alternatively save the registry keys using VBA and determine the version number you need for the registry path with `Application.Version` which returns `16.0` for Office 2019 Professional.
One method for registry manipulation can be found here: [Read and write from/to registry in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345238/read-and-write-from-to-registry-in-vba) (you will find other methods too if you google).

#### Solution 3: Batch File

You can also create the keys with a batch file:

```shell
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\StatusBar" /v MaxValue /t REG_DWORD /d 1
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\StatusBar" /v MinValue /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

use `reg /?` for more info.

#### Solution 4: Powershell

And finally Powershell is possible too

```shell
set-itemproperty -path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\StatusBar -name MaxValue -Value 1
set-itemproperty -path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\StatusBar -name MinValue Value -Value 1
```

See [Working with Registry Entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/working-with-registry-entries?view=powershell-7.1).

The Excel version can be read in Powershell with

```shell
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$xl.Version
$xl.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl)
Remove-Variable xl
```

by opening an Excel ComObject and asking for the version.

Comment: Way to tackle the challenge! I knew there had to be a way, hopefully this can be a resource for others. The challenge in goolging this question lies in the fact that VBA `Application.StatusBar` is a thing, but doesn't do what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: I found `Application.Version` to be a great way to get the "Internal Version Number!"

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution using purely VBA. Thanks @PEH for his [great detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68194553/5079799) w/ many alternatives.

All you'd need to do is call `SetMinMaxEnabledInExcelStatusBar` module somehow.

Note: You could totally skip the `SetRegKey` and just `SaveRegKey` each run, I'm not sure which method I like better. I mostly used the `SetRegkey` as my testing module and then left it alone once it worked and I'm of the mindset why mess w/ registry if the `"RegKeyCurrentStateInt = RegKeyDesiredStateInt"`

```
Public Const DWordRegKeyEnabled As Integer = 1
Public Const DWordRegKeyDisabled As Integer = 0

Public RegKeyStr As String, RegKeyLocStr As String, RegKeyNameStr As String
Public RegKeyDesiredStateInt As Integer, RegKeyCurrentStateInt As Integer
Public RegKeyFoundBool As Boolean
```

---

```
Public Sub SetMinMaxEnabledInExcelStatusBar()

 RegKeyDesiredStateInt = DWordRegKeyEnabled
 
 RegKeyLocStr = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\" & Application.Version & "\Excel\StatusBar\"
 RegKeyNameStr = "MaxValue"
 RegKeyStr = RegKeyLocStr & RegKeyNameStr
 Debug.Print "RegKeyStr = " & RegKeyStr
 Call SetRegKey(RegKeyStr, RegKeyDesiredStateInt)
 RegKeyNameStr = "MinValue"
 RegKeyStr = RegKeyLocStr & RegKeyNameStr
 Debug.Print "RegKeyStr = " & RegKeyStr
 Call SetRegKey(RegKeyStr, RegKeyDesiredStateInt)
 
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub SetRegKey(RegKeyStr As String, RegKeyDesiredStateInt As Integer)
 
 RegKeyFoundBool = RegKeyExists(RegKeyStr)
 Debug.Print "RegKeyFoundBool = " & RegKeyFoundBool
 
 If RegKeyFoundBool = False Then
  Debug.Print "RegKeyFoundBool = False"
  Call SaveRegKey(RegKeyStr, RegKeyDesiredStateInt)
 Else
  Debug.Print "RegKeyFoundBool = True"
  
  RegKeyCurrentStateInt = ReadRegKeyVal(RegKeyStr)
  Debug.Print "RegKeyCurrentStateInt = " & RegKeyCurrentStateInt
 
  If RegKeyCurrentStateInt <> RegKeyDesiredStateInt Then
   Debug.Print "RegKeyCurrentStateInt <> RegKeyDesiredStateInt"
   Call SaveRegKey(RegKeyStr, RegKeyDesiredStateInt)
  Else
   Debug.Print "RegKeyCurrentStateInt = RegKeyDesiredStateInt"
  End If
 End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function ReadRegKeyVal(RegKeyStr As String) As Integer
 ReadRegKeyVal = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead(RegKeyStr)
End Function
```

---

```
Public Function RegKeyExists(RegKeyStr As String) As Boolean

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegRead (RegKeyStr)
  RegKeyExists = True
  Exit Function
  
ErrorHandler:
  RegKeyExists = False
End Function
```

---

```
Public Sub SaveRegKey(RegKeyStr As String, RegKeyDesiredStateInt As Integer, Optional RegKeyType As String = "REG_DWORD")
 CreateObject("WScript.Shell").RegWrite RegKeyStr, RegKeyDesiredStateInt, RegKeyType
 Debug.Print "Generated --> " & RegKeyStr & "," & RegKeyDesiredStateInt & "," & RegKeyType
End Sub
```